# Logs and statements with Snowflake and Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a possibility that we may lose some messages if we use snowflake kafka connector. For example if the kafka connector reads the message and commits the offset before the message is written to the variant table, then we will lose that message. Is this a scenario that can happen if we use kafka connect

If you have any examples, these are welcome as well, thank you!

Comment: Kafka Connect doesn't guarantee exactly once semantics, but I think it would only commit offsets after the database transaction completed

Comment: This might be better addressed to the developers of the connector through a github issue at https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/issues

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation[from snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-overview.html#fault-tolerance)

> Both Kafka and the Kafka connector are fault-tolerant. Messages are neither duplicated nor silently dropped. Messages are delivered exactly once, or an error message will be generated. If an error is detected while loading a record (for example, the record was expected to be a well-formed JSON or Avro record, but wasn’t well-formed), then the record is not loaded; instead, an error message is returned.

Limitations are listed as well. Arguably, *nothing is impossible*, but if you don't trust Kafka I'd not use Kafka at all.
How and where you could loose messages depends on your overall architecture too, like are records written into the Kafka-Topics you're consuming, how do you partition?